# SLF4J summary and not line by line

Tags: log4j, slf4j

I am using SLF4J on my web server, but it is difficult to collate all the lines that are associated to a request.

If I have 4 log entries, like this:

```
logger.info("Entering method A. Request ID is "+requestId);
logger.info("Did something. Request ID is "+requestId);
logger.info("Did something else. Request ID is "+requestId);
logger.info("Exiting method A. Request ID is "+requestId);
```

The entries will be added to the log files, interspersed with other entries of other requests.

Is it possible to keep the same log statements in the same places, but save them to the log files in one summary?

Preferably, for the example, instead of having 4 lines spread on the log file, the text would be only one entry, at the end of method A.